# Response.addHeader causes 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: c#, .net, webmethod

I have written a Login WebMethod ,if the details are ok i want to redirect to another page.

this is my code :

```
[WebMethod]
public String Login(String email, String password){

    String result=WSUtils.GetData("check_login", email, password);
    if (result.Equals("True")){

          Context.Response.Clear();
          Context.Response.Status = ""+System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Redirect;
          Context.Response.AddHeader("Location", "/admin/index.html");
          Context.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
          Context.Response.End();

    }
return result;
}
```

this code causes 500 (Internal Server Error) 
thank you

Comment: Is there some special reason for not using `Response.Redirect`?

Comment: Looking at your code more closely, I have to question what you are trying to accomplish here.  This code is inside a `WebMethod` that returns a `string`.  Whatever is calling that method is expecting a `string` to be directly returned. Redirecting in the middle of that method seems like it would break the logic of whatever is calling that.

Comment: Response.redirect doesn't work .so what is the right approach to redirect ?

Comment: That depends on what you are actually **intending** to do here.  My assumption is that you have some client calling this code as a web method.  If the username and password is correct you want **that client** to redirect. Is this correct?

Comment: yes this is exactly what is try to do .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is trying to do too much.  It is being called as a `WebMethod` that returns a string, but you are trying to redirect inside it.  The problem is that redirecting inside this kind of function doesn't make sense.  Whatever called `Login` only knows about the `string` result.  It could be said that the return type of the function represents a "contract" between the client and the server.  By redirecting inside the function you are breaking this contract and doing something unexpected that the client can't interpret, and the server infrastruction that handles the WebRequest can't handle.

The proper way to do this is to have your `Login` function stick to the "contract", **just** return the result.  It should be the responsibility of the calling code to interpret the result of that code, by parsing the `string` result, and taking action on it.

To do this, remove the entire "if" block from your server call, and change the code on the **client** to look (something) like this:

```
if (myWebServiceClient.Login(email, password) == "True")
{
    //I logged in, do success stuff here
}
else
{
    //Display some kind of login failed message
    //Redirect here
}
```